# For how many numbers between 1 and 50 will $\frac{(n^2 - 1)!}{n!^n}$ be an integer?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, integers

So far my hunch is that for all the numbers of the form $p^r$ where $p$ is any prime number and $r$ is any positive integer would dissatisfy the above condition. So all numbers not of this form should be the answer. But I don't have any concrete proof just few test cases for small numbers and the idea that $\frac{n^2!}{n!^n}$ is an integer for all $n$. The last $n^2$ is used to cancel out the last $n$ from denominator.

Kindly help.

Comment: This is https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2019_AMC_10A_Problems/Problem_25

Comment: @JetChung thanks!